# Enterprise Mode IE (EMIE) Behavior in Web Analytics

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Microsoft introduces [Enterprise Mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687.aspx) IE (EMIE). It allows IE11 to dictate in which Doc Mode/Quirks a site should render in.

So, I was wondering how does it behave and what browser will it report to analytics. The browser is IE11, but the site is being rendered in as IE8 Doc Mode. Would it report IE11 or IE8?

Answer (score 0):

Analytics work off the user agent string. For enterprise mode to work the best it would use the user agent string of the legacy version you are telling it to use with the application. So if your application was written for IE 8 then you should configure EMIE to use IE 8 emulation for the application and the analytics should perceive it as IE 8 based on the user agent string.